# CQEngine + large result set: sort or group by multiple attributes performance

Tags: cqengine

I have a fairly large collection (~10MM elements), and I need to run queries that return fairly large result sets (~500K elements). I need those elements grouped by or ordered based on two attributes:

1. The first attribute (let's call it `A`) has about 2MM distinct instances.
2. The second attribute (let's call it `B`) has about 10 distinct instances.

All elements with matching `(A, B)` pairs need to be grouped together for processing purposes. I could, potentially, add them to a map and then process the map; however, given that I need to run quite a few of those queries in parallel, I would rather avoid creating the intermediate map and instead extract/process the groups directly from the result set.

One way to do this is to sort by `(A, B)`; this works, as I can extract the chunks that belong together from the result set and process them as I go. However, the query execution times are way too slow. I tried adding different types of indexes to `A` and `B`, but nothing seems to help with performance. For the record, I don't need them sorted; I only need the matching `(A, B)` elements to show together in the result set.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a few ways to optimize this.

In CQEngine I tend to use the term *ordering* to describe the desired outcome, and then there can be multiple ordering strategies to achieve the ordering.

The default behavior in CQEngine is to use what's known as the *materialize* ordering strategy, which involves copying all of the results matching a query into a temporary collection which is then sorted explicitly. This does not scale well to large ResultSets, so I'm not surprised that it would be slow for a ResultSet of 500K elements in this case. See [OrderingStrategies](https://github.com/npgall/cqengine/blob/master/documentation/OrderingStrategies.md) for details.

However the TL;DR is: you could request CQEngine to use the *index* ordering strategy.

**Index-accelerated ordering on attribute A**

In your example you need to order results by (A, B), so you would request CQEngine to use an index on attribute A to accelerate the ordering. As you need to order by A and then B, this won't *completely* eliminate the need to sort results, because if the engine finds multiple objects which match the query colocated in a single bucket in index A, it will still have to explicitly sort a small number of matching objects in that bucket by attribute B in order to achieve the overall ordering by (A, B).

All other things being equal, based on a collection size of 10MM elements, and 2MM distinct values for A, you can expect each bucket in the index on A to contain 5 objects. So I'd expect that this approach could achieve a major reduction in time-to-first-result latency. It might not be perfect though...

**Partial indexes**

The approach above generally works well for data which resembles time-series, where A might be a timestamp, and you want to search recent items and your want to order results by recency too.

However a downside of using an index on attribute A to drive the search for workloads which don't resemble time-series, is that the ordered index on A which is being traversed to achieve the ordering of results, might be *polluted* with lots of objects which don't match the query you are trying to accelerate. So this can introduce *filtering overhead*.

You didn't mention much about your queries. For example do you know the set of queries in advance, or are they completely arbitrary?

I ask about this, because if you know which queries you expect in advance (or at least some fragments of the queries you expect in advance), then you could set up [PartialIndex](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://raw.githubusercontent.com/npgall/cqengine/master/documentation/javadoc/apidocs/com/googlecode/cqengine/index/support/PartialIndex.html)es on attribute A which are configured with *filter queries* you expect to find in your workload.

Partial indexes (plus enabling the index ordering strategy) can be a great way to *mitigate index pollution*, which means an index can be used to accelerate the ordering of large ResultSets, and it won't be susceptible to excessive filtering. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried both suggestions, but CQ seems to simply ignore the indexes and go for the post-sorting. I tried to play with the INDEX_ORDERING_SELECTIVITY, but when I specify that option, then the sorting stops working.

Comment: Going into more details, `A` and `B` are both strings, and they are not part of the where clause. I don't know the set of queries in advance, this is for a shared cache service, and there is no telling how people will query it.

I have also tried to create a composite attribute on `A` and `B`, simply concatenating them, and then creating a `NavigableIndex` on it, but this also seems to have no effect - it still does the post-sorting.

Comment: I do have control, however, of the "use case" query I mentioned above.

Comment: There are a number of requirements that need to be met, in order for the engine to leverage an index for ordering. There is however a way to have it log its decisions which might tell us what's going on: https://github.com/npgall/cqengine/blob/2.12.1/code/src/main/java/com/googlecode/cqengine/engine/CollectionQueryEngine.java#L356

Comment: I guess stack overflow is not the best medium to debug this particular issue in detail. There is a discussion forum for the project. If you'd like to post details of the problem there, I can help you to enable debug logging to see what's going on. http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cqengine-discuss